# Square roots with different heights

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

What can I do to the square root symbols have the same size.

[image]

Comment: Use a `\mathstrut` in each `\sqrt`. Or, in the first `\sqrt` apply `\vphantom{M_1^2}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I use often this trick :-) +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix:

```
\[
\frac{2C_1 p^2 \sqrt{p^2+M_{}^2}\sqrt{p^2+M_1^2}}{1}
\]
```

[image]

The second square root symbol is higher because of the `M_1^2` inside it has both a subscript and a super script. In this case, the super script moves upward a little bit to leave room for the subscript. The simple solution is to add a surplus `_{}` for the first `M^2` inside the first root. If you need the exact same height, then use `M_{\phantom{1}}^2`.

Comment: This problem arises if you try to centralize the formula by using double sign $$\frac{2C_1 p^2 \sqrt{p^2+M_{}^2}\sqrt{p^2+M_1^2}}{1}$$

Comment: @Boris: Don't use `$$`. See [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/4301)